KVM networks DHCP from local router
I'm new to KVM, so pardon me for stupid questions.
What I'm trying to do is:
My host is on my private LAN receiving an IP address from the local router via DHCP (ip4 and 6)
I have several KVM VM's installed on the host, each of them shall also receive an IP4/6 from the router via DHCP (I'll assign static IPs in the DHCP server)
I created a yaml file:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0f1:
            dhcp4: yes
            dhcp6: yes
    bridges:
      br0:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: yes
        interfaces:
          - enp3s0f1

This has created a bride interface which I can present to the VM, however the host does not have an IP anymore now.
Also I will need to have several of these "bridges" for each of my VM's
I followed these instructions here:
https://www.dzombak.com/blog/2024/02/Setting-up-KVM-virtual-machines-using-a-bridged-network.html
Thanks for your help!
David

After starting the VM, do the brctl show and bridge link commands show the network interface of the VM connected to the bridge? And the command networkctl -a, brctl show and  networkctl status br0 show the bridge correctly connected to the physical interface?
